# SearchExecutor not returning results with non privileged user

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-search, object-model

for short "testing user" will be "TE", "administrator user" will be "admin".

I am currently working in a sharepoint project in visual studio which deploys a webpart that uses the search engine. With the admin the code returns values, but with TE is not the case. TE has rigths over some of the items.

My objective is to do a search with TE and obtain the items he has access to. Do you know a way to do this?

Rigth now the code looks like this:

```
internal static DataTable Search(string query, string urlSite, List<string> properties, KeywordInclusion typeSearch)
{
  DataTable dataTable = null;
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(urlSite))
  {
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);
    keywordQuery.fill( query, properties, typeSearch);

    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

    ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.FirstOrDefault();
    dataTable = resultTable.Table;

    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
  }
  return dataTable;
}
```

Extension method:

```
internal static KeywordQuery fill(this KeywordQuery keywordQuery, string query, List<string> properties, KeywordInclusion typeSearch)
{
  int rowLimit = 10000;
  int queryTimeOut = 30000;
  bool duplicated= false;

  keywordQuery.QueryText = query;

  keywordQuery.KeywordInclusion = typeSearch;
  keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = !duplicated;
  keywordQuery.RowLimit = rowLimit;
  keywordQuery.Timeout = queryTimeOut;

  foreach (string propertie in properties)
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add(propertie);

  return keywordQuery;
}
```

Update:
With the standart webparts for searching it is also not returning for TE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a similar problem is probably because you are taking the wrong aproach, like me.

Try to create a page that uses default webparts and try to recover data with that. If you can't, that means that is an error in your sharepoint configuration or you have to crawl.

In my case: I had to make a full crawl. found it thanks to the following link.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4c01f79c-c7df-496b-a9a0-247e04895eef/sharepoint-2013-search-no-results-for-new-users-before-full-crawl?forum=sharepointsearch